# Compiling fmt/format.h using C++20

Tags: c++, c++20, fmt

I have been trying to compile this program:

```cpp
import <iostream>;
import <numbers>;
import <cmath>; 
//import <fmt/format.h>;
#include <fmt/format.h>

int main()
{
    // 2 square feet pond surface for every 6 inches of fish
    const double fish_factor { 2.0/0.5 }; // Area per unit length of fish
    const double inches_per_foot { 12.0 };
    double fish_count {}; // Number of fish
    double fish_length {}; // Average length of fish

    std::cout << "Enter the number of fish you want to keep: ";
    std::cin >> fish_count;
    std::cout << "Enter the average fish length in inches: ";
    std::cin >> fish_length;

    fish_length /= inches_per_foot; // Convert to feet
    std::cout << '\n';
    // Calculate the required surface area
    const double pond_area {fish_count * fish_length * fish_factor};

    // Calculate the pond diameter from the area
    const double pond_diameter {2.0 * std::sqrt(pond_area / std::numbers::pi)};
    std::cout << fmt::format("Pond diameter required for {} fish is {} feet.\n", fish_count, pond_diameter);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried compiling it using:

1. `g++ -c -fmodules-ts -x c++-system-header iostream numbers cmath -std=c++20`
2. `g++ -fmodules-ts -o fish_pond fish_pond.cpp -I /usr/local/inlcude -L /usr/local/lib/ -std=c++20`

but I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccObU8Zj.o: in function `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > fmt::v10::format<double&, double const&>(fmt::v10::basic_format_string<char, fmt::v10::type_identity<double&>::type, fmt::v10::type_identity<double const&>::type>, double&, double const&)':
fish_pond.cpp:(.text._ZN3fmt3v106formatIJRdRKdEEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEENS0_19basic_format_stringIcJDpNS0_13type_identityIT_E4typeEEEEDpOSD_[_ZN3fmt3v106formatIJRdRKdEEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEENS0_19basic_format_stringIcJDpNS0_13type_identityIT_E4typeEEEEDpOSD_]+0xac): undefined reference to `fmt::v10::vformat(fmt::v10::basic_string_view<char>, fmt::v10::basic_format_args<fmt::v10::context>)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have tried doing `import <fmt/format.h>` in the first step and compiled with the flag `-lfmt` but nothing seems to work. I'm using g++ (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0.

Here is what I get using flags -Wall --verbose

```
g++ -Wall --verbose -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -o fish_pond fish_pond.cpp -lfmt
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:amdgcn-amdhsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-11/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,m2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-11 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --enable-libphobos-checking=release --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --enable-cet --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-11-XeT9lY/gcc-11-11.4.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,amdgcn-amdhsa=/build/gcc-11-XeT9lY/gcc-11-11.4.0/debian/tmp-gcn/usr --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto-lean --enable-link-serialization=2
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 11.4.0 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-Wall' '-v' '-std=c++20' '-fmodules-ts' '-o' 'fish_pond' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/cc1plus -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu -D_GNU_SOURCE fish_pond.cpp -quiet -dumpbase fish_pond.cpp -dumpbase-ext .cpp -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -Wall -std=c++20 -version -fmodules-ts -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat-security -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -o /tmp/ccBeX1O1.s
GNU C++20 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) version 11.4.0 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 11.4.0, GMP version 6.2.1, MPFR version 4.1.0, MPC version 1.2.1, isl version isl-0.24-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/11"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/include/c++/11
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/11
 /usr/include/c++/11/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C++20 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) version 11.4.0 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 11.4.0, GMP version 6.2.1, MPFR version 4.1.0, MPC version 1.2.1, isl version isl-0.24-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: d591828bb4d392ae8b7b160e5bb0b95f
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-Wall' '-v' '-std=c++20' '-fmodules-ts' '-o' 'fish_pond' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 as -v --64 -o /tmp/ccGVhwRY.o /tmp/ccBeX1O1.s
GNU assembler version 2.38 (x86_64-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-Wall' '-v' '-std=c++20' '-fmodules-ts' '-o' 'fish_pond' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64' '-dumpdir' 'fish_pond.'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/collect2 -plugin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/cc42iVWy.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu --as-needed -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -pie -z now -z relro -o fish_pond /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/crtbeginS.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../.. /tmp/ccGVhwRY.o -lfmt -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/crtendS.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccGVhwRY.o: in function `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > fmt::v10::format<double&, double const&>(fmt::v10::basic_format_string<char, fmt::v10::type_identity<double&>::type, fmt::v10::type_identity<double const&>::type>, double&, double const&)':
fish_pond.cpp:(.text._ZN3fmt3v106formatIJRdRKdEEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEENS0_19basic_format_stringIcJDpNS0_13type_identityIT_E4typeEEEEDpOSD_[_ZN3fmt3v106formatIJRdRKdEEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEENS0_19basic_format_stringIcJDpNS0_13type_identityIT_E4typeEEEEDpOSD_]+0xac): undefined reference to `fmt::v10::vformat(fmt::v10::basic_string_view<char>, fmt::v10::basic_format_args<fmt::v10::context>)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: The error you are getting essentially seems to be `undefined reference to fmt::v10::vformat`. Unless you are using fmt as a header-only library, you should link against it by providing the `-lfmt` option to the g++. Also, if the question is purely about fmt, why do you complicate it by bringing in the modules and such. Use regular `#include`s. (Or, if you have a question about modules, ask that as a separate question, not involving fmt.)

Comment: @heap underrun. I was only showing the steps I used to compile, so one can reproduce it. I did provide the -lfmt flag but it gave the same error. Are you saying all my headers should be #inlcude and none should be import ?

Comment: have you built and installed fmt before using it? if yes, then adding -lfmt should have worked. Please check that you really have /usr/local/lib/libfmt.a or /usr/local/lib/libfmt.so

Comment: btw, you don't have to specify -I/usr/local/include and -L/usr/local/lib, these are part of default include and library search paths. But some libraries are installed into /usr/local/lib/some-directory, then you need to specify that full path to some-directory.

Comment: hello @ivan.ukr I do have libfmt.a
`ls  /usr/local/lib/
cmake  libfmt.a  pkgconfig  python2.7  python3.10  python3.9`
and I also compiled it with
`g++ -fmodules-ts -o fish_pond fish_pond.cpp -std=c++20 -lfmt`
but still getting the error:
`usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cce8T01n.o: in function `std::__cxx11::basic ...`

Comment: hello @ivan.ukr this is my first time and I built it folowing the instructions from [link](https://fmt.dev/latest/usage.html)

Comment: You may want to add -Wl,--verbose switch to get verbose linker messages. Also `nm -C /usr/shared/lib/libfmt.a | grep fmt::v10::vformat` may provide a clue.

Comment: @ivan.ukr I edited the question to include the output of the flags. my libfmt.a is in `/usr/local/lib/` and not in `/usr/shared/lib`
Here is the output of `nm -C /usr/local/lib/libfmt.a | grep fmt::v10::vformat`

`000000000003d50 T fmt::v10::vformat[abi:cxx11](fmt::v10::basic_string_view<char>, fmt::v10::basic_format_args<fmt::v10::context>)
000000000000040a t fmt::v10::vformat[abi:cxx11](fmt::v10::basic_string_view<char>, fmt::v10::basic_format_args<fmt::v10::context>) [clone .cold]`

Comment: I think there may be something with how libfmt itself was compiled. Try changing ypur `#import` into `#include`, lowering c++ standard to c++11 and making some other changes to make it compile as c++11 code. Then see if it links.

Comment: Hi @ivan.ukr changing the import to include enables the code to compile and run. My aim is to compile using import as this is needed on what I'm working on.
Thanks